# In mongodb terminal update only documents that have this field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How in terminal can i make mongodb only update a field of documents it exists and not add a field to document with new value which don't already have this field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**$exists**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) could help

```
db.collection.update({field_name: {$exists: 1}}, {$set : {field_name: 'new val'}})
```

Comment: how would i do it nodejs with `mongodb`

Comment: these would help http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html and http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/overview/quickstart/